# Checking for empty excel files BEFORE attempting upload

Tags: jquery

In web application (using struts 2.3 and Hibernate 3.6), I am uploading an excel sheet by using jQuery function. So my question is how to check empty excel sheet before attempting the uploading using jQuery functions? Please, any suggestions?

This is code for checking the extension:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sumbitFileForUploadHyperlink").click(function() {
        var fileUpload = $("#fileUpload").val();
        if (fileUpload == '') {
            $('#alertDialogFileUpload').modal('show');  
        } else {
            var extension = $("#fileUpload").val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(extension, ['xls','xlsx','csv']) == -1) {
                $('#alertDialogInvalidFileExtension').modal('show');        
            } else {
                $("#fileUploadForm").submit();
            }           
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: it depends on how you produce the export. please provide some relevant code.

Comment: Hi Paolo,  Sorry for wrong terms. export means I am uploading the excel sheet.